# Does QActionGroup emits signals?

Tags: qt, pyqt

For some reason I am not able to make QActionGroup to emit triggered() signal. I connected it with my method instance, but for some reason it doesn't work. If I connect one of actions with the same method all looks working.

```
def modeChanged(self, action):
  print "CHANGE"
w = QMainWindow()
mouseModeGroup = QActionGroup(w.toolbar)
//adding some actions into group
w.connect(mouseModeGroup, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.modeChanged)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [new signal and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) method (available in PyQt 4.5 or above)?

So for your example:

```
mouseModeGroup.triggered.connect(self.modeChanged)
```

Or old school (not recommended):

```
#The Signal you have for triggered was incorrect
w.connect(mouseModeGroup, SIGNAL("triggered(QAction*)"), self.modeChanged)
```